# Different pointer types for the same address

Tags: c, embedded, 8051

I am relative new to programming so I apologize if my question is basic.

Situation:

I have several float values and an array of pointers to each value. Ex:

```
float nr1=1.15;
float nr2=2.30; 
float nr3=23.34;
```

....

```
float * my_address_array[3]; 

my_address_array[0] = &nr1;
my_address_array[1] = &nr2;
my_address_array[2] = &nr3;
```

To access one element, I can use:

```
float temp_value; 
float ** ptr_value;
```

...

```
ptr_value = &my_address_array[0];

temp_value = **( ptr_value+0); // copy nr1 to temp
temp_value = **( ptr_value+1); // copy nr2 to temp
temp_value = **( ptr_value+2); // copy nr3 to temp
```

So far so good. On my system float occupies 32 bits (8051 microcontroller). I need to take one float number and separate it into four 8 bit variables. Example for nr2:

My attempt was:

```
unsigned char storage1; 
unsigned char storage2; 
unsigned char storage3; 
unsigned char storage4;
```

...

```
storage1 =(unsigned char) ((**( ptr_value+1)) >> 24) ;
storage2 =(unsigned char) ((**( ptr_value+1)) >> 16) ;
storage3 =(unsigned char) ((**( ptr_value+1)) >> 8) ;
storage4 =(unsigned char) ((**( ptr_value+1)) & 0xff) ;
```

I get bad operand type. It seems that I cannot use bit shift operations with float numbers (at least google sais that). I can add a new pointer, as in:

```
char ** ptr_char_value;
```

...

```
ptr_char_value = &my_address_array[0];   // generates warning

storage1 = (*(*( ptr_char_value+1)+0));
storage2 = (*(*( ptr_char_value+1)+1));
storage3 = (*(*( ptr_char_value+1)+2));
storage4 = (*(*( ptr_char_value+1)+3));
```

I do get a warning (which is fair) that I am using a char type pointer for a float value. I am also not sure how reliable this is. Can anyone advise a better solution?

Thank you!

*Edit: The code is for a 8051 microcontroller. I would like to make it as fast/optimal as possible.*

Comment: `ptr_char_value = &my_address_array[0];` is dangerous indeed. case: pointer arithmatic on `ptr_char_value`. what is your target?

Comment: In C, `char` type aliases all types, so it's OK.

Comment: The microcontroller in question is from Silabs C8051F96x (8 bit)

Comment: You should reduce that pointer nonsense. `**( ptr_value+0)` can be written as `*ptr_value[0]`. Also, use a lot more temporary variables; it's ugly and unnecessary to repeat same pointer calculations on multiple rows.

Comment: I do agree that the array access looks better than pointer access. However pointer access is faster (tested). Since I might need to do hundreds of operations I will have a performance hit. It might be a compiler optimization thingy, but I prefer using pointer than spending time optimizing array access (and change a chunk of code afterwards).In regards to more temporary values, the code looks different than what I posted. I only put an example to point the issue.

Comment: @CalinTamaian All array accesses are pointer arithmetric under the hood. Either you made error on your testing, or your compiler has some serious issues.

Answer (score 1):

with this, you are getting pointer to pointer to value

```
ptr_char_value = &my_address_array[0];
```

I don't understand how this should work.

---

It would be better to use pointer to float directly. Cast it to char array and get separate bytes.

```
char * ptr_char_value = (char *)(my_address_array[0]);
storage1 = ptr_char_value[0];
storage2 = ptr_char_value[1];
storage3 = ptr_char_value[2];
storage4 = ptr_char_value[3];
```

---

EDIT:
It is also question if you realy need array of pointers to floats. It is possible to have struct, cast it to array of bytes and use these bytes directly for something.

```
struct my_data_type {
    float nr1;
    float nr2;
    float nr3;
}

struct my_data_type my_data;

my_data.nr1 = 1.15;
my_data.nr2 = 4.75;
my_data.nr3 = 8.95;

char * ptr_char_value = (char *)&my_data;

// nr1
storage1 = ptr_char_value[0];
...

// nr2
storage5 = ptr_char_value[4];
...

// nr3
storage9 = ptr_char_value[8];
...
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, this is the best approach, you just need be aware of endianness issues - does `ptr_char_value[0]` contain the most significant byte or least significant byte?

Answer (score 0):

try this. You should type cast before you can shift the data. Include stdint.h

```
      storage1 = (uint8_t) ((((uint32_t)**( ptr_value+1))) >> 24) & 0xFF );
```

Comment: Nope. Undefined behaviour, accessing `float` via `uint32_t *` is not permitted.

Comment: @EOF You are right, but on a 8051 platform you can't get align problems

Comment: @jeb: Is this C, or is it some butchered, non-standard C-ish language only supported on weird and wonderous architectures/platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with the title:

> Different pointer types for the same address

That's code smell. In C, aliasing objects through an incompatible pointer type results in undefined behavior, unless the incompatible aliasing type is (qualified or unqualified, signed or unsigned) character type.

More precisely, an object of type cv-qualified or unqualified `T` may only be accessed through a pointer to qualified or unqualified `T`. Additionally, if `T` is an integral type, then accessing via its (qualified or unqualified) signed or unsigned counterpart is permitted as well.

This is colloquially called the "strict aliasing rule".

Hence, you can't do

```
float f;
*(int *)&f
```

even if `sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)`.

The possible solutions:

1. Use `memcpy()`, like this (preferred):

```
float f = 3.14;
int i;
memcpy(&i, &f, sizeof f);
```

2. Use a union (C99 only – this is UB too in C89…):

```
union {
    float f;
    int i;
} pun = { .f = 3.14 };
printf("%d\n", pun.i);
```

Comment: @EOF Your first point is valid, but for second N1570 6.5.2.3, note 95 says:  *"If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation."*

Comment: @user694733 The part you are quoting says that can produce undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501 It *can*, but not necessarily. Standard basically says: *"It's not UB, but there are risks that you should know about."*

Comment: @2501 There is a clear distiction here. Type punning is allowed on unions as long as programmer makes sure to avoid possible trap presentations.

Comment: @EOF Implementation defined behavior is not the same thing as undefined behavior. If you don't know what you are talking about, then don't downvote for good reason.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to separate float in 4 variables?
That don't make any sense because of how `float` is represented in computer.

[image: float in c]

First bit S is sing, 0 for positive 1 for negative numbers. Then 8 bits of exponent and remaining 23 for mantissa.
So, there is nothing useful you can do with 8bit parts, because they are on their own meaningless.

Comment: It may be used just for storage to some memory, it is not intend to be used directly so it make sense in some situations